# There is a tree, there is a tree

Tags: grammar

He pointed the tree.

"There is a tree."

Then he pointed another tree.

"There is a tree."

Then he say, "**There is a tree, there is a tree.**"

He pointed tree A then pointed tree B.

Does it sound natural?

Comment: _He pointed **at** the tree._ ... ... _"There is a tree, **and** there is **another** tree."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @P.E.Dant points out, usually one would say

> There is a tree **and** there is a tree.
>   There is a tree, **and** there is **another** tree.
>   There is a tree, **and** there is **also** a tree.

but if the speaker is very young, for example only 5 years old

> There is a tree!  There is a tree!

might be expected.  It also sounds like the speaker is very excited about seeing a tree!